# Trying to query elasticSearch for data I put via kafka to logstash, Not able to see any of my documents! what could be the reason?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

logstash config :

```html
input {
    kafka {
            bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
            topics => ["log-test-8"]
            codec => "json"
    }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "log-test-8"
      workers => 1
    }
}
```

Can you give some examples of how to get "type" and specific data I sent in my kafka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common errors:
- No valid yaml as logstash.conf
- Instance not reachable

Did you try to run logstash from the commandline? Can you provide debug output of logstash? (For reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-command-line.html)

Comment: yes I did, data is getting into elasticsearch from my kafka via logstash.